# Use array variable in as argument to command

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, nested

I have to use an array in a command that is stored in a variable:

```
# Array
DOMAIN="${DOMAIN:-example.com}";
GETIP=$( dig +short "${DOMAIN}" ) # No output
```

The following command is working:

```
dig +short example.com
```

Comment: What does `echo ${DOMAIN[@]}` outputs?

Comment: You have no arrays in that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce your problem:

```
DOMAIN="${DOMAIN:-example.com}";
GETIP=$( dig +short "${DOMAIN}" )
echo "$GETIP"
```

Output:

```
93.184.216.34
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used the Variable outside of the scope.